# Team Wise Record Edit

Tags: profile, permission-sets, teams

I have defined different teams in salesforce.I want to see if
members of  each teams may edit each others' leads but not those of other teams.

Eg . User 1
   Profile : Treatment Consultant
   Role : Team TC

```
User 2 
Profile : Treatment Consultant
Role : Team TS
```

I understand that if I go the profile settings and change the lead modify all checkbox then irrespective of teams they would be able to modify all leads.

I just want Team TS members to edit TS members leads and TC members to edit TC members leads only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need Public Groups for your requirement and use sharing rules to allocate the Sharing access .

[image]